# How to install a callback function in swift

Tags: swift, unsafe-pointers

I'm trying to use DiskArbitration and install a first callback function, which is DADiskAppearedCallback, but i am stuck at the DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback statement, with this error:

**'DeviceManager' is not convertible to 'UnsafeMutablePointer<()>'**

I need to pass a DeviceManager instance to the callback in order to populate the array inside...

Here is my code:

```
class DeviceManager {
  var devices = [Device]()

  func diskAppearedCallback(disk: DADisk!, context: UnsafeMutablePointer<()>) {
    NSLog("Disk: \(DADiskGetBSDName(disk))")

    // Create and Add a device here...     
  }

  var callback = CFunctionPointer<(DADisk!, UnsafeMutablePointer<()>) -> Void>()

  init() {

    var session = DASessionCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault).takeRetainedValue()    

    DARegisterDiskAppearedCallback(session, kDADiskDescriptionMatchVolumeMountable, callback, self) 

    ...      

  }
}
```

Thank's in advance for any help.

Comment: any reason why context is `UnsafeMutablePointer<()>`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Swift CFunctionPointer to pass a callback to CoreMIDI API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514176/using-swift-cfunctionpointer-to-pass-a-callback-to-coremidi-api)