# Convert Swift closure to CFunctionPointer?

Tags: c, swift, audio, xcode6, closures

Is it possible to pass a closure from a Swift program into an API where the corresponding argument has been marked as `CFunctionPointer`?

I've come across indications (e.g. [here](http://dev.eltima.com/post/93497713759/interacting-with-c-pointers-in-swift-part-2)) that this was not possible with (by now obsolete) beta versions of Xcode 6.

> However, you cannot call a C function pointer or convert a closure to
>   C function pointer type.

Is it possible by now and if so how?

For instance, how could one define a closure in Swift that would be accepted as `AudioServicesSystemSoundCompletionProc` in a call to [`AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/AudioServicesAddSystemSoundCompletion)?

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26830840/1789384) answer employs both Swift and Objective-C to arrive at a solution. Is one possible with a Swift class alone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C Wrapper for CFunctionPointer to a Swift Closure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138658/objective-c-wrapper-for-cfunctionpointer-to-a-swift-closure)

Answer (score 4):

No, not yet possible with Swift alone.

> However, you cannot call a C function pointer or convert a closure to
>   C function pointer type.

Is still in effect and up to date. There is no way to define or convert closure to C function in Swift. You can only refer to already defined C functions.

Comment: Can you please quote from a current piece of Apple documentation to back this up. (Then I'll accept the answer.)

Comment: Basically, `However, you cannot call a C function pointer or convert a closure to C function pointer type.` is still in effect.