# FSEventStreamCreate in swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, nsevent

I am looking at monitoring the access of a directory on our file system and it seems that FSEvent is the way to go.

From what I understand I need to set up a FSEventStreamCreate.

The examples I have found are for Objective-C and I don't quite understand how to use `FSEventStreamCreate`.

Can someone give me some ideas on how one might monitor a folder?

Comment: FSEventStreamCreate needs a C function pointer as the second argument, and these are not (yet) available in Swift (compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514176/using-swift-cfunctionpointer-to-pass-a-callback-to-coremidi-api).

Comment: Ahhh thanks Martin, what a shame! Do you know of anything available I may be able to use?

Comment: perhaps this might be another route to take - http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/08/monitoring-a-folder-with-gcd/

Answer (score -1):

You have to declare a var as function type and define it

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173903/swift-2-cannot-invoke-fseventstreamcreate-with-an-argument-list-of-type)