# Swift 2 Cannot invoke 'FSEventStreamCreate' with an argument list of type

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift, swift2

Using Swift 2 and Xcode 7 beta 2 (Build: 7A121l) I get this compile error using FSEventStream API and @convention(c).

Any advice would be awesome, thanks!

```
internal class FileSystem {

init () {

    let allocator: CFAllocator? = kCFAllocatorDefault

    // Create FSEventStream and return valid FSEventStreamRef
    // Alias FSEventStreamCallback - CFunction

    typealias FSEventStreamCallback = @convention(c) (ConstFSEventStreamRef, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, UInt, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, UnsafePointer<FSEventStreamEventFlags>, UnsafePointer<FSEventStreamEventId>) -> Void

    let callback: FSEventStreamCallback = {
        (streamRef, clientCallBackInfo, numEvents, eventPaths, eventFlags, eventIds) -> Void in
        print ("changed")
        // handle file event
    }

    let context: UnsafeMutablePointer<FSEventStreamContext> = nil
    let pathsToWatch: CFArray = [NSHomeDirectory() + "/Dir"]
    let sinceWhen: FSEventStreamEventId = UInt64(kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow)
    let latency: CFTimeInterval = 1.0
    let flags: FSEventStreamCreateFlags = UInt32(kFSEventStreamCreateFlagNone)

    let eventStream = FSEventStreamCreate(
        allocator,
        callback,
        context,
        pathsToWatch,
        sinceWhen,
        latency,
        flags
    )

    FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(eventStream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode)
    FSEventStreamStart(eventStream)

}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the wrong signature (UInt not Int):

```
typealias FSEventStreamCallback = @convention(c) (ConstFSEventStreamRef, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, Int, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, UnsafePointer<FSEventStreamEventFlags>, UnsafePointer<FSEventStreamEventId>) -> Void
```

This compiles fine:

```
init () {

    let allocator: CFAllocator? = kCFAllocatorDefault

    // Create FSEventStream and return valid FSEventStreamRef
    // Alias FSEventStreamCallback - CFunction
    typealias FSEventStreamCallback = @convention(c) (ConstFSEventStreamRef, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, Int, UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, UnsafePointer<FSEventStreamEventFlags>, UnsafePointer<FSEventStreamEventId>) -> Void
    let callback: FSEventStreamCallback = {
        (streamRef, clientCallBackInfo, numEvents, eventPaths, eventFlags, eventIds) -> Void in
        print ("changed")
        // handle file event
    }


    let context: UnsafeMutablePointer<FSEventStreamContext> = nil
    let pathsToWatch: CFArray = [NSHomeDirectory() + "/Dir"]
    let sinceWhen: FSEventStreamEventId = UInt64(kFSEventStreamEventIdSinceNow)
    let latency: CFTimeInterval = 1.0
    let flags: FSEventStreamCreateFlags = UInt32(kFSEventStreamCreateFlagNone)

    let eventStream = FSEventStreamCreate(
        allocator,
        callback,
        context,
        pathsToWatch,
        sinceWhen,
        latency,
        flags
    )

    FSEventStreamScheduleWithRunLoop(eventStream, CFRunLoopGetCurrent(), kCFRunLoopDefaultMode)
    FSEventStreamStart(eventStream)

}
```

Comment: You are welcome. I found out that some error messages from the Swift compiler are cryptic. What helps me is breaking down composed statements in smaller block, replicating by hand what essentially the syntax analyzer & code generator should get better at telling you as things are maturing.