# SSLReadFunc in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, ssl

I'm trying to send some data over a secure connection in Swift. Does anybody know how the SSLReadFunc / SSLWriteFunc must look ?

The apple docs only provide an example for obj-c:

```
OSStatus SSLWrite ( SSLContextRef context, const void *data, size_t dataLength, size_t *processed );
```

I tried it like this:

```
func write ( context : SSLContextRef, data : UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, length : size_t ) -> OSStatus{

}
```

But when calling SSLSetIOFunctions(sslcontext, read, write) i am getting an error:

```
error: '(SSLContextRef, data: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>, length: UInt) -> OSStatus' is not convertible to 'SSLReadFunc'
    SSLSetIOFuncs(sslcontext, read, write)
                              ^
Security.readFunc:1:5: note: in initialization of parameter 'readFunc'
let readFunc: SSLReadFunc
```

Comment: I think you're out of luck. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514176/using-swift-cfunctionpointer-to-pass-a-callback-to-coremidi-api

Comment: Yes. It is (currently) not possible to assign a Swift function/method/closure to a C function pointer.

Comment: Is there another solution in swift to send data over a secure connection?